# Unicode: Python 3 ignores LC_CTYPE on Ubuntu when run as CGI

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, unicode, locale

I'm new to python and recently ran into this problem w. Unicode characters in filenames my scripts handle. Python seems to ignore the OS locale settings and is not using utf-8 encoding.

The system is Ubuntu 16.04, output from "locale" below:

```
strnad@apczbrno46:~$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

LC_ALL and LC_CTYPE seem to be set to an UTF-8 encoding correctly. Files on the filesystem can be created with Unicode characters flawlessly.

However, if I run a python script which tries to manipulate a file w. Unicode characters in the filename, it fails as follows.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# encoding: utf-8 
# Global modules
import re
import sys
import csv
import os
import cgi
import cgitb;cgitb.enable()


print("Content-Type: text/html")     # HTML is following
print("")
print ("<html><head></head><body>")  # blank line, end of headers

import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
print (("sys getfilesystemencoding: ")  +   (sys.getfilesystemencoding()))

filename = ("Pracovní smlouva.docx")

try:
    os.remove(filename)
    print ("at least tried to delete")
except OSError:
    print("File not deleted")
```

Error:

```
[Thu Jul 12 14:10:27.145862 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 1346] [client 10.0.8.37:63831] AH01215: Error in sys.excepthook:: /var/www/html/test.py
[Thu Jul 12 14:10:27.146065 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 1346] [client 10.0.8.37:63831] AH01215: Traceback (most recent call last):: /var/www/html/test.py
[Thu Jul 12 14:10:27.146226 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 1346] [client 10.0.8.37:63831] AH01215:   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/cgitb.py", line 268, in __call__: /var/www/html/test.py
[Thu Jul 12 14:10:27.146333 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 1346] [client 10.0.8.37:63831] AH01215:     self.handle((etype, evalue, etb)): /var/www/html/test.py
[Thu Jul 12 14:10:27.146488 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 1346] [client 10.0.8.37:63831] AH01215:   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/cgitb.py", line 288, in handle: /var/www/html/test.py
[Thu Jul 12 14:10:27.146578 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 1346] [client 10.0.8.37:63831] AH01215:     self.file.write(doc + '\\n'): /var/www/html/test.py
[Thu Jul 12 14:10:27.146855 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 1346] [client 10.0.8.37:63831] AH01215: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\\xed' in position 1724: ordinal not in range(128): /var/www/html/test.py
[Thu Jul 12 14:10:27.146889 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 1346] [client 10.0.8.37:63831] AH01215: : /var/www/html/test.py
[Thu Jul 12 14:10:27.146960 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 1346] [client 10.0.8.37:63831] AH01215: Original exception was:: /var/www/html/test.py
[Thu Jul 12 14:10:27.147057 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 1346] [client 10.0.8.37:63831] AH01215: Traceback (most recent call last):: /var/www/html/test.py
[Thu Jul 12 14:10:27.147199 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 1346] [client 10.0.8.37:63831] AH01215:   File "/var/www/html/test.py", line 28, in <module>: /var/www/html/test.py
[Thu Jul 12 14:10:27.147269 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 1346] [client 10.0.8.37:63831] AH01215:     os.remove(filename): /var/www/html/test.py
[Thu Jul 12 14:10:27.147540 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 1346] [client 10.0.8.37:63831] AH01215: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\\xed' in position 7: ordinal not in range(128): /var/www/html/test.py
```

I tried u number of suggested solutions, such as:

```
# sys.getfilesystemencoding = lambda: 'UTF-8'
#import locale
# locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.utf-8')
# os.environ["PYTHONIOENCODING"] = "utf-8"
# locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'en_US.UTF-8')
# sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter("utf-8")(sys.stdout.detach())
# sys.stdout = io.open(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w', encoding='utf8')
```

but sys.getfilesystemencoding always returns "ASCII", which seems to be the core of the problem.

If i try to do the same from console under the same user, utf-8 is found:

```
strnad@apczbrno46:~$ python
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getfilesystemencoding()
'utf-8'
>>>
```

Could you point me in the right direction please?

Thank you,

Martin

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322410/set-encoding-in-python-3-cgi-scripts

Answer (score 0):

[Set encoding in Python 3 CGI scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322410/set-encoding-in-python-3-cgi-scripts)

Apparently, I should have searched a while longer:)

This was the solution:

```
Summarizing @cercatrova 's answer:

Add PassEnv LANG line to the end of your /etc/apache2/apache2.conf or .htaccess.
Uncomment . /etc/default/locale line in /etc/apache2/envvars.
Make sure line similar to LANG="en_US.UTF-8" is present in /etc/default/locale.
```